# Android RecyclerView DefaultItemAnimator - Items moving weirdly

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with a simple multicolumn layout RecyclerView which is best reproducible on tablets. I have created a basic example with fully functional source code below, maybe it is easier to quickly run it, instead of trying to understand what I mean ;)

The main problem on tablets (where I have a grid layout) is, that items get strangely rearranged when hiding specific items and displaying them again (via notifyItemRemoved() and notifyItemInserted()). I think this can be even reproduced with removing and inserting only the first item. The layout manager inserts an extra row at the top and moves items from the first line below to fill it. (The example below removes and inserts every third item, starting with the first one)

I have different types of items (in the example red, green and blue items) and I want to toggle a specific type of items (in the example you can toggle the red items with a click on the FloatingActionButton).

The weird behavior that I want to fix can be reproduced by just clicking the FAB twice without scrolling before. This would first filter the red items and then display them again. When toggling the filter the second time you will notice that there is a row of items inserted above and items from the first row are moved to fill it. 
If you didn't notice during the animation, just scroll up after toggling the filter.

I would expect that the first row stays where it is and that just the red items get displayed again.

Does anybody know how to fix that?

Here is the activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private TestAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    ((FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            toggleFiltered();
        }
    });

    final int columnCount = getColumnCount(300);
    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, columnCount);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adapter = new TestAdapter();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
}

private void toggleFiltered() {
    final boolean filtered = adapter.isFiltered();
    adapter.setFiltered(!filtered);
    if(filtered) {
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(3);
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(6);
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(9);
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(12);
    } else {
        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(0);
        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(3);
        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(6);
        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(9);
        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(12);
    }
}

int getColumnCount(final int dpThreshold){
    final Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    final DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(outMetrics);

    final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    final float dpWidth = outMetrics.widthPixels / density;

    return ((int) dpWidth) / dpThreshold;
}

class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    public static final int TYPE_RED = 0;
    public static final int TYPE_GREEN = 1;
    public static final int TYPE_BLUE = 2;

    private boolean filtered = false;

    public boolean isFiltered() {
        return filtered;
    }

    public void setFiltered(final boolean filtered) {
        this.filtered = filtered;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
        final View view = new View(parent.getContext());
        view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 500));

        int color = Color.RED;
        if(viewType == TYPE_GREEN){
            color = Color.GREEN;
        } else if (viewType == TYPE_BLUE){
            color = Color.BLUE;
        }

        return new TestViewHolder(view, color);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(final int position) {
        if(!filtered) {
            if ((position + 3) % 3 == 0) {
                return TYPE_RED;
            }
            if ((position + 2) % 3 == 0) {
                return TYPE_GREEN;
            }
        } else {
            if ((position) % 2 == 0) {
                return TYPE_GREEN;
            }
        }
        return TYPE_BLUE;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(filtered) {
            return 10;
        }
        return 15;
    }

    class TestViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TestViewHolder(final View itemView, final int color) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(color);
        }
    }
}
}
```

And here is the layout code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/root_layout"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/root_layout"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/root_layout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/root_layout"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/root_layout"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I should mention that the problem is not in `DefaultItemAnimator`. If you set your animator to `null`, you would have the same behavior. And actually there is no problem at all. The behavior is expected, as you're just inserting the item into the first position of your `TestAdapter`, and then other items are shifting, but your `RecyclerView` is staying at the same position.

So all you need is just add `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);` line in the end of your `toggleFiltered()` method, so it will scroll up, once you've applied the filtering. And it will work as you wish.

Comment: Hey rom4ek, you're right, the problem is not in DefaultItemAnimator, it seems to come from the LayoutManager, which is responsible for the positioning... If I would set the LayoutManager to null, then I could apply your fix. But I want the animation to take place and with the animation the behavior is just confusing and in my opinion it is not expected at all.

Comment: Hm, I guess you didn't get my answer - there is no need to set neither `DefaultItemAnimator` nor `LayoutManager` to null. ***You should just add `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);` in the end of your `toggleFiltered()` method, and it will work.***

Comment: Ok, you're right, scrolling to position 0 really does fix the problem, even if I don't get the reason ;) In my real app I still have some issues left when the list is not scrolled to the top, but maybe I just have to figure out a generic way to calculate the position that I have to scroll to.

Comment: Do you mean that `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);` is not working in your real app? If so, you can try to do that after some delay, like `recyclerView.postDelayed(() -> recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0), 50)`, to make sure your filtering was performed already.

Comment: No, scrollToPosition(0) works, but I don't always want to scroll to top. Some issues remain when the user has already scrolled down, but your answer was definitely a step in the right direction, therefore I will award you with the bounty ;)

Answer (score 0):

its not weird. because you notifyItemInserted(0). it is insert Item. not notifyDataSetChanged(). adapter is showing item keep going. its Green Item. you notifyItemInserted(0) insert Red, still adapter showing first item is Green(it poisition is 1). because adapter notifyItemInserted(0) has before showing first item is Green.